# Delphi TFloatField.DisplayFormat for numeric fields less than 1.0

Tags: database, delphi, string-formatting, vcl, tfield

This is my procedure.

```
procedure format_integer_field(Atable: TDataSet);
 var i: integer;
begin
 if Atable.Active then
 if Atable.FieldCount > 0 then
 with Atable do
 begin
  for i:= 0 to FieldCount-1 do
  if (Fields[i] is TIntegerField) then
  begin
   (Fields[i] as TIntegerField).DisplayFormat := '###,###';
   (Fields[i] as TIntegerField).EditFormat := '#';
  end
  else
   if (Fields[i] is TFloatField) then
  begin
   (Fields[i] as TFloatField).DisplayFormat := '###,###.##';
   (Fields[i] as TFloatField).EditFormat := '#.##';
  end;
 end;
end;
```

This is work fine until a number like "0.9" has been entered and result will be ".9".
How can I have thousand separator and zero before floating point that smaller than "1".

Comment: I can understand wanting a zero, but a thousands separator for a number that only has one digit before the decimal separator, are you sure you want that? It would make 0.9 look like 0,000.9.

Comment: @hvd maybe that is the way he tries to align numbers "by the comma" or by any other strategy

Comment: @Arioch'The Considering the OP likes the behaviour for other numbers (1 doesn't become 0,001), I doubt that, but yes, it's possible.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I didn't notice that 0,000.9 and its will be bigger problem. I just want my numbers looks good.

Comment: Does `###,##0.0#` do it for you ?

Comment: @HughJones Please Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format you need is `###,##0.0#`

Answer (score 5):

Try  `(Fields[i] as TFloatField).DisplayFormat := '##0,000.00';`

As you did read in documentation at http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Using_Default_Formatting_for_Numeric,_Date,_and_Time_Fields it says

> Default formatting is performed by the following routines:
>
> - FormatFloat -- TFloatField, TCurrencyField

And how you did read in the following documentation pages

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.FormatFloat
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TNumericField.DisplayFormat

the documentation quotes

> - 0 ->     Digit placeholder. **If the value** being formatted **has a digit** in the position where '0' appears in the format string, then
>     that digit is copied to the output string. **Otherwise, a '0' is
>     stored** in that position in the output string.
> - # ->     Digit placeholder. **If the value** being formatted **has a digit** in the position where '#' appears in the format string, then
>     that digit is copied to the output string. **Otherwise, nothing is
>     stored** in that position in the output string.

So by using "#" in the formatting pattern you tell Delphi "i do not need any digits (and thousands separators with them) in this place, but you might put them if you want" - and since Delphi does not want to put leading zeros - you don't have any. However, if you really need those digits and the thousands separator with them, you put "0" instead of "#" and that way you tell Delphi "the digits just need to be here, whether you want to put them or not"