# How to use DisplayFormat to get a leading zero on values < 1.00

Tags: delphi

I'm using

```
DisplayFormat := ',####,####.#';
```

Items that are zero are shown as blank.

Is there a way to change the above format so that values that are zero continue to be blank, but items < 1.0 appear with a leading zero, like 0.65 ???

The format:,

```
DisplayFormat := ',####,###0.#';
```

shows the leading zero when values are less than 1.0.

But, unfortunately, items that are 0 are no longer blank.

I need, thus, some sort of conditional formatting.

Related to [Delphi TFloatField.DisplayFormat for numeric fields less than 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399729/delphi-tfloatfield-displayformat-for-numeric-fields-less-than-1-0)

Comment: What is `DisplayFormat`? Is it `TFloatField.DisplayFormat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DisplayFormat has three parts separated by semicolon. The third part represents the value 0.

```
DisplayFormat := ',####,###0.#;;';
```