# Returned query values are different type in FastReport 4

Tags: firebird, fastreport

I am trying to get a numeric value of my firebird sql query.

In IBExpert the data types are correct "Numeric(18,2)" but when it comes to FastReport it displays me not the Numeric18,2 datatype. It cuts the ,00 off.

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `SELECT AVG(CAST (PQ AS NUMERIC(18,2))) FROM PROC ORDERED BY..` this is my "pseudo"code to get my datasets to work with in FastReport.
In ibexpert I get the result 50,00. In FastReport I get 50 as output in a memo / rich text.
FastReport always cuts off the last 0s I guess. If I get a result like 41,20 in ibexpert, in FastReport I get 41,2.

Comment: Don't provide relevant information in comments, you should edit your question, but this is not a [mcve]. In any case, not knowing fast report at all, this suggests it is either retrieving or rendering it as double precision, or you might be using a dialect 1 database instead of dialect 3.

Comment: You maybe mistake two different things - the numeric data, which Firebird passes to your program, and the textual data that FastReport creates form this numeric data and passes to you. You need to read FR manuals about data formatting. For example in usual Delphi db libs there is `TField` which has `OnGetText` and `DisplayFormat` properties: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399729/ There should be similar properties in FastReport, probably in its table columns objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is retrieved properly, you need just to display it well formatted.

Set the display format of the text box as described in [documentation](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/docs/vcl/FR6/HTML_EN/index.html?values_formatting.htm).

If the text box contains different formats for multiple values you need to use [inline formatting](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/docs/vcl/FR6/HTML_EN/index.html?inline_formatting.htm) for each value.